# How would I create a text file and fill it with sudo permission in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create and fill a file in a directory that requires sudo permission. I've tried:

```
$ echo 'hello' > sudo tee /data/hello
```

However, I just get the output that /etc/file does not exist:

```
$ cat /data/hello
cat: /data/hello: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can't reproduce that

Comment: What is the exact output? `tee` should create the destination file for you.

Comment: If you don't have `/etc` that would explain it, but this seems unreproducible on any reasonably regular system.

Comment: Are you sure you **actually** tested with the **exact** command? If you ran `sudo tee /etc/some/file`, and `/etc/some` didn't exist, that would have the behavior described. `sudo tee /etc/file`, by contrast, is a completely legitimate way to escalate privileges used to write to `/etc/file`. I'd suggest reproducing the issue with `set -x` enabled, and incorporating that *exact*, unedited log into the question.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you for editing in your actual command; that makes this answerable.

Comment: I updated it. Thanks for the direct link, but I had to dig a bit as the redirected question wasn't specifically the same.

Comment: ...btw, try running `ls -l sudo` to demonstrate that your command given in the log created a `sudo` file when run; you might also run `cat sudo` to view its contents, which should be the string `hello tee /data/hello` (as these arguments were passed to `echo`, not run as a separate command).

Comment: I just tired that and it say no such file or  directory

Comment: Has to be in the same directory (and Vagrant guest instance, if applicable), where you also ran `echo 'hello' > sudo tee /data/hello`. (It looks like that was `~` from the log, so `cat ~/sudo` if logged into that same account and instance).

Comment: ohh ok, that's pretty neat.

Comment: ...so, right now, you've got an internally contradictory question -- one part of it says command A failed, one part says you actually used command B. It should probably be edited to be consistent, or closed as being result of a typo.

Comment: Ah, Thanks for the heads up, I'll edit it as it is confusing. Thanks for being so helpful. stackoverflow is a bit rough to approach.

Comment: ...unfortunately, the current edit set goes as far as to invalidate existing answers -- that's rather explicitly not kosher here. Indeed, it doesn't leave any question at all, but appears to be only an answer itself. If there *is* no remaining question, the appropriate action is just to delete the question -- which will also have the side effect of refunding reputation lost to downvotes.

Comment: Rolled back edits that removed context needed to make answers understandable. **Answers or solutions do not belong in the question itself -- the question should be a question, the answers should be answers.** If you want to add your own answer, the way to do that is with the _Add an Answer_ button.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question has been edited to include a log of the problem being introduced, which includes the command:

```
# Taken from edited question
$ echo 'hello' > sudo tee /data/hello
```

In bash (which allows redirection operators at any point in a simple command), this is precisely equivalent to running:

```
# From question, with redirection moved to end to make actual behavior more readable
echo 'hello' tee /data/hello > sudo
```

That is, it's creating a file **named `sudo` in your current directory**, not using `sudo` to run `tee` (in the above, `tee` is just an argument to `echo`).

What you want, by contrast, is:

```
# CORRECT: Using a pipe, not a redirection
echo 'hello' | sudo tee /data/hello
```

with a pipe (`|`) rather than a `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the required sudo privileges you could use an editor like [vi](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html) or [nano](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/)

```
sudo vi /etc/file
```

or

```
sudo nano /etc/file
```

If you don't have sudo for those programs you can su to root first and then try:

```
sudo su -

vi /etc/file
```

or

```
nano /etc/file
```

Comment: These aren't necessary. `tee` *does* create destination files.

Comment: (and see the OP's edit to the question, adding the actual command they ran -- which makes the problem clear).

Comment: Ha ! I did get confused there for a second !  :--)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it all on one command line, you can make sure that the file exists by running touch(1) on it. E.g.

`sudo touch /etc/file && echo "Some text" | sudo tee /etc/file`

Comment: Not necessary. `tee` opens its output file with `O_CREAT` flag, and so will create the file if it doesn't exist -- you can check that with `strace` if you like.

Comment: (and see the OP's edit to the question, adding the actual command they ran -- which makes the problem clear).

Comment: Yup, that makes more sense, thanks.